# build-time weaving with openjpa at using spring created persistence unit

Tags: java, spring, jpa, openjpa

[This documentation states:](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-ant.html)

> Note: as a prereq to running the enhance task, I copied my persistence.xml file to my /build directory. You might not need to do this, but the persistence.xml has to be in the classpath.

This implies to me the task needs to determine through the persistence.xml file what files need enhancing.

Currently my runtime weaving does not work. I may need help with that, but i would preferrably like my classes to be pre-enhanced as we will be making heavy use of entity classes.

Can pre-enhancement be performed on entity classes assembled in a spring-built Persistence Unit?

Comment: byte-time weaving? It is a short form of "runtime bytecode weaving"?

Comment: Quoted from the doc u mentioned: `The persistence.xml doesn't have to be complete. The required elements are the persistence-unit (any legal name will do), and the provider (you have to identify openjpa). You can identify the classes to be enhanced either in this file or in the enhancer task ant project.`  Therefore just make up a dummy persistence.xml containing the persistence unit and provider should be good enough